# Can't import nodejs module using absolute file path (meteor, linux. Works fine on Windows)

Tags: node.js, linux, meteor, require

I'm trying to import a file in server.js of a meteor project on Linux. For example:

```
 var temp = require('/home/HaveAGitGat/Documents/test.js');
```

I get the following error:

```
 Error: Cannot find module '/home/HaveAGitGat/Documents/test.js'
```

The confusing thing is this works fine on Windows using meteor. It also works fine on Linux when running pure nodejs files without meteor.

Any ideas on a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your test files inside your meteor project, and it's recommended that you do so. Putting absolute paths in your code means that you are locked to that folder structure, which isn't great for portability.

For example, if you wanted me to collaborate on your project, I would have to modify all the require statements to make it work, and when I commit those changes it would break it for you.

Here's an alternative: Create a folder in `imports/test` to hold all your test files, so that you can import them with statements like this:

```
import testCase1 from '/imports/test/test1
```

Then your code is clean, portable, and your project is self-contained.

See https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html for more info

Comment: Thanks for the info. The issue is I'm trying to read user-configurable data from the user's Documents folder. I've already configured everything so that it works fine between operating systems and this method works well in my other nodejs applications. You wouldn't need to modify the require statements as the program handles the paths automatically so that it can always read the correct files from your Documents folder. Like I mentioned, it works fine on Windows, just need to find the solution for Linux Ubuntu.